# Saving a yeast starter

Tags: yeast-starters

I made a beer 2 weeks ago and had 2 liters of yeast starter I made for it. I used about 1.5 liters and saved the rest for later in a sanitized jar in the fridge. Is the starter still fine? Is there anything I need to do before using it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The starter is still good in that time. Very roughly, a 2L starter, presumably from a vial or smack pack, [probably netted you between](http://www.brewersfriend.com/yeast-pitch-rate-and-starter-calculator/) 200bn and 400bn cells. If you used 3/4 of it, you probably have 50-100bn cells left … about the amount in a smack pack/vial. As such, you should probably make a new starter from the remains of the previous one.

Comment: All of the above assumes really good sanitation when you used and stored the original starter.